# Update error in relation to Nivdia 331

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, updates

The last few Software updates I've run have come up with an error in relation to the `nvidia-331` package. After the update I've run the command `optirun glxgears` and it seems to run fine. Also tried it with `optirun firefox` and that opens fine as well.

My question is, do I need to do anything so as not to get this error anymore?

Below is a screengrab of the error I get.

[image: Error screengrab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed Nvidia drivers from xorg-edgers ppa, and you have kernel 3.13. It may not be well.

I suggest removing xorg-edgers ppa and installing same driver from Ubuntu repository. Xorg-edgers pack for newer kernels.

```
 sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-331
```

Comment: Will this have any impact on bumblebee which I also have installed?

Comment: Bumblebee should work. The driver is same. But there is no 100% guarantee, that ppa did not break any configs.